# Media queries switch div from block to inline

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm pretty new to div-based css, and so I think I might be asking a misdirected question here.

In my page, I want to have a div across the middle of the page. Within this bar is a logo image, left-aligned, and, inline with the logo but floated right, the main navigation menu.

When the width of the page is reduced below a certain threshold I would like the navigation menu to appear directly below the logo.

To accomplish this I've attempted to use media queries in my CSS. In the case that my window is below 700px, I would like the menu to be floated right and have a top margin. Otherwise, I want it to be block, so it will go to the next line. (I am also using jQuery to keep the middle bar centered across the height of the page).

My media queries seem to provide the right effect for the initial window width, but when I expand my window from below to above 700 pixels, the navigation menu remains on the next line. It does not display inline with the logo.

Am I approaching this the wrong way, is there an additional style I should be specifying in my CSS, or do I simply not understand the display style?

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
<script
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onResize() {
        var bar_height = $("#middlebar").height();

        $("#middlebar").css("top",
                ($(window).height() - bar_height) * .45 + "px");

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        onResize();
        $(window).on("resize", onResize);
    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">

#middlebar {
    background: #AAAAFF;
    padding-top: -5px;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}

#navmenu {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.08em;
}

@media ( max-width : 700px) {
    #navmenu {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}


@media ( min-width : 701px) {

#navmenu {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 16px;
}


}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="middlebar">
        <img src="logo.png" height="60px" id="logoimg"></img>
        <div id="navmenu">
            <span> 
                <a href="#">home</a>
            </span> 

            <span>
                <a href="#">specials</a>
            </span> 

            <span>
                <a href="#">about</a> 
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**See the live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Gpk4c/

Comment: Your question is confusing. Based on the live version, what you need to be done? Maybe post a picture explaining the expected behavior. In the fiddle when I change the size of rendered result the menu content float to right.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need either jQuery nor media queries to make an element flow down or stay vertically centered to a page. Play a bit more with `position` and `display` properties. [This guide](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) maybe can help.

Comment: Links are not answers. Answers on SO are expected to be self-contained. Please [review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887)  and add enough detail to your answer to make it not completely reliant on external links.

Comment: I think the crux of my question might be that when I have a large screen width, I would like the navigation bar to be right-aligned, but when it is at a smaller width, I would like the navigation bar to be left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to float the image. The order of your HTML with the image first makes the floated nav menu fall below the image, even when it's floated right. The following extra CSS puts the links in line with the image at the larger size:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

Then to make the image and links stack at the smaller size, you can add a `clear` rule:

```
@media ( max-width : 700px) {
  #navmenu {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: both; /* This kicks the nav menu below the image */
  }
}
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw74w/)